# Firebase best practises with FCM topics or device groups

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use FCM and I'm not sure which option would apply best to my situation.
Essentially I have artists in a database that users can follow, so for each artist I have a variable number of users that follow it.

Now if an artist releases something new, I want to send out a notification to all of the users that follow it. And here are my only options:

1. For each user do: FCM send with users's token
2. Subscribe a user to each "artist" topic (artist identifier) and send a notification to the topic of the artist identifier
3. Create a device group with an identifier (artist identifier) and add user to the device groups for all the artists.

Issues I have with each of the options:

1. Would create a large number of send promises (for each user)
2. Would need to subscribe to all of the artists (there is no subscribeToTopics functionality, only for a single topic)
3. Same as (2.) would need to create a device group for each artist and add the user to each of them.

I'd usually go with the 1. option and I was wondering if it can be done with let's say 1000 Users (so essentially a for loop 1000 times and each creates a send promise).

Is there anything I'm missing to send notifications to a large group of users which each could have a large amount of groups / topics?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely pick topics for your use-case, they're pretty much made for this. While option 1 would also be possible, it just feels senseless to manage the subscriptions yourself in this case.

If you want to allow someone to also subscribe to news about all artists, create a topic `all` and then send news about any artist to a [condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_condition): `('The Beatles' in topics || 'all' in topics)`.

Comment: So I‘d need to call subscribeToTopic for every artist that the user wants to follow essentially?

Comment: Yes. Same as you'd have to register them for each artist, if you'd pick option 1.

Comment: Well in my database I already know the users for each artist and therefore can get all users for an artist and its fcm tokens. So I‘d only need to loop through the users and send a notification to each token, but I‘m not sure if that is better or worse than managing topics

Comment: There is no clear better or worse, which is why I answered with what I would do. Both can work perfectly fine, there's just less management overhead in your code with option 2 (in exchange for having less control over the fan-out process).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have same problem and I choose use topics, too. But now, I have other problems: If user logout from a device, I need to unsubscribe this device to all topics of artists, who user followed. It's take a long time if user subscribe multiple topics. Is there any ways for this problems? or I should move this process to background job?

Comment: I am interested in the same question as @TuanTran and I also wonder: if the user follows other artists on another device, this means that I need to do regular polling, to see if the artists the user follows changed, right? Otherwise the user would still receive notifications about artists they no longer follow, and vice-versa they wouldn't receive notifications for artists they followed on other devices... is that correct?